# splashscreen issue with iOS 9.3 but ok with 8.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, ios9, splash-screen

My current issue is the following I'm using the "Default.png" nomenclature in order to have a splashcreen following the device's language.

In `iOS 8.1` there's no issue (at least on simu 4,4s,5, 5s,6..) but with `iOS 9.3` (simu AND device from 5 to 6+), the splash screen doesn't appear and the application has the "size" of an `iPhone 4 application`.

I'm using the last version of Xcode and the project was an old project (iOS6) upgrade to `iOS8` following the client requirements.

Any clue ?

[my splashscreens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z85r.png) for the following formats

- 320x480 640x960 640x1136 750x1334 1242x2208

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the xcasset ?

Comment: No issue with asset, but correct me if i'm wrong, i can't localize the asset

Comment: If I recall correctly you can create localized xcassets, but due to a bug, it wasn't taken into account in the last version of Xcode.